# 3D Plot of Implied Volatility in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to plot 3D Surface of Implied volatility in Python. I have the following set of data but when I am trying to plot them it doesn't plot well as we can see in Excel. Could you please help me to plot the surface for the following set of data?

[image: Sample surface]

Sample Data

|  | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0.0565 | 0.0876 | 0.6545 | 0.5643 | 0.0765 |
| 200 | 0.7675 | 0.0777 | 0.0654 | 0.8765 | 0.0651 |
| 300 | 0.0434 | 0.1234 | 0.5455 | 0.3498 | 0.7512 |
| 400 | 0.2223 | 0.5412 | 0.5354 | 0.1111 | 0.7433 |
| 500 | 0.2388 | 0.3421 | 0.7111 | 0.2398 | 0.0666 |

Comment: 1- please provide the data as text, 2- provide a schematic of the expected graph

Comment: @mozway I have updated the question with both required information. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First load your data as DataFrame (`df` here) with `pandas.read_excel` to obtain:

```
       2020    2021    2022    2023    2024
100  0.0565  0.0876  0.6545  0.5643  0.0765
200  0.7675  0.0777  0.0654  0.8765  0.0651
300  0.0434  0.1234  0.5455  0.3498  0.7512
400  0.2223  0.5412  0.5354  0.1111  0.7433
500  0.2388  0.3421  0.7111  0.2398  0.0666
```

Then use `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X, Y = np.meshgrid(df.columns.astype(int), df.index)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, df.to_numpy(), cmap=cm.gist_rainbow)
```

output:

[image: surface plot]